# Is substituting self in init method a bad practice?

Tags: objective-c, subclass, init

I've read this from Appledoc regarding the famous (or infamous?) `init` method

> In some cases, an init method might return a substitute object. You must therefore always use the object returned by init, and not the one returned by alloc or allocWithZone:, in subsequent code.

So say I have these two class

```
@interface A : NSObject
@end

@interface B : A
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *usefulArray;
@end
```

with the following implementation

```
@implementation A
+(NSMutableArray *)wonderfulCache {
    static NSMutableArray  *array = nil;
    if (!array)
        array = [NSMutableArray array];
    return array;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        // substituting self with another object
        // A has thought of an intelligent way of recycling
        // its own objects
        if ([self.class wonderfulCache].count) {
            self = [self.class wonderfulCache].lastObject;
            [[self.class wonderfulCache] removeLastObject];
        } else {
            // go through some initiating process
            // ....
            if (self.canBeReused)
                [[self.class wonderfulCache] addObject:self];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL) canBeReused {
    // put in some condition 
    return YES;
}
@end

@implementation B
-(id)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        // setting the property
        self.usefulArray = [NSArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

When B calls `init`, the `[super init]` might return a substituted A object, and won't it cause an error when B tries to set the property (which A does not have)?

If this does cause an error, how can we implement the above pattern in the correct way?

## Update: attaching a more real-world specific problem

Here's a C++ class called `C` (its use would be explained later)

```
class C
{
    /// Get the user data pointer 
    void* GetUserData() const;

    /// Set the user data. Use this to store your application specific data.
    void SetUserData(void* data);
}
```

Say the aim of `A` is to act as a wrapper of `C`; and it's vital that a one-to-one relationship should be maintained between `A` and `C` **at all times**.

So I come up with the following inteface and implementation

```
@interface A : NSObject
-(id)initWithC:(C *)c;
@end

@implementation A {
    C *_c;
}
-(id)initWithC:(C *)c {
    id cu = (__bridge id) c->GetUserData();
    if (cu) {
        // Bingo, we've got the object already!
        if ([cu isKindOfClass:self.class]) {
            return (self = cu);
        } else {
           // expensive operation to unbind cu from c
           // but how...?
        }
    } 
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _c = c;
        c->SetUserData((__bridge void *)self);
        // expensive operation to bind c to self
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

This works for the time being. Now I'd like to subclass `A` so I come up with `B`

```
@interface B : A
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *usefulArray;
@end
```

A problem surfaces now as `A` does not have the knowledge of how to properly unbind an instance. So I have to modify the above code into

```
@interface A : NSObject {
    C *_c;
}
-(id)initWithC:(C *)c;
-(void) bind;
-(void) unbind;
@end

@implementation A 
-(id)initWithC:(C *)c {
    id cu = (__bridge id) c->GetUserData();
    if (cu) {
        // Bingo, we've got the object already!
        if ([cu isKindOfClass:self.class]) {
            return (self = cu);
        } else {
            NSAssert([cu isKindOfClass:[A class]], @"inconsistent wrapper relationship");
           [(A *)cu unbind];
        }
    } 
    if (self=[super init]) {
        _c = c;
        c->SetUserData((__bridge void *)self);
        [self bind];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) bind {
    //.. do something about _c
}

-(void) unbind {
    // .. do something about _c
    _c = nil;
}
@end
```

Now `B` only has to override `bind` and `unbind` to make it work.

But when I think about it, all `B` wants to do is to have an additional array `usefulArray`, does it really warrant this much of work...? And the idea that writing `unbind` is only for your subclass to replace you in the 1-to-1 relationship with the C++ object just seems weird (and inefficient as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be one misunderstanding:
An `init` method must always return an instance of the receiving class's type.
If `-[A init]` is called via `[super init]` in `-[B init]`, `self` is an
(allocated but not yet initialized) instance of class `B`. Therefore `-[A init]`
*must* return an instance of class `B` (or of a subclass).

So if you decide to "recycle" objects, you must ensure that an object of the
correct class is recycled.

I cannot tell if "substituting self in init" is bad practice in your case, that would
probably depend on the objects and the `canBeReused` condition. It is mainly done by
"class clusters" such as `NSNumber`, `NSArray` etc.

Comment: Indeed, what I did in my code is to put a `isKindOfClass:` check when I try to use a cached object. However, I feel this is hacky and not very elegant. That's why I'm trying to find a perfect solution (if there's really one)

Comment: @yulan6248: You could override `wonderfulCache` in `B` (just copy the method to B.m), then each subclass automatically has its own cache. Alternatively, use a dictionary where `self.class` is the key and the cache is the value.

Comment: My real problem is outlined as a response to ikaver in his answer. I need to establish a one-to-one relationship between a C++ object and its wrapper; and at one time I realize that I have the need to subclass this wrapper class. Now my only chance to keep the consistency is to revoke the relationship between the old wrapper object and its corresponding C++ object first when a subclassed wrapper tries to init with the same C++ object...

Comment: @yulan6248: I would suggest that you update your question with more information, so that other readers know your "real problem" without browsing through all comments. Perhaps add some details about the C++ class, the Objective-C wrapper class and the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and should not produce any errors.

What they mean by "might produce a substitute object" is not that it might return an object of a type of class you are expecting, but rather that their super init method might create a different instance of the same class.

Thus, the return for [super init] might be a different object than `self` is, which is why you need to do `self = [super init]` rather than just `[super init]`. You can, however, safely assume that the object will be initialized as you expect as long as you have no coding errors.

This is also why you put `self = [super init]` in an if statement; if for some reason the initializer returns `nil`, you dont want to continue setting things and you just want to return self.

Comment: The code *will* cause an error if `[B init]` returns an `A` object from the cache and not a `B` object.

Comment: I just tested it with two simple lines `A *a = [A new]; B *b= [B new]` AND IT THROWS AN ERROR as expected `unrecognized selector in -[A setUsefulArray:]`